# Angular/Javasript: download an existing csv file from server

Tags: javascript, angular, download

I want to allow visitor to download a CSV file from server using Angular 7.

I have seen few websites but most of them explain to create CSV file dynamically from data and use blob creation than download the folder. But I have already have CSV file on the server and want to download it from server side to client side.

Comment: Just make an AJAX Request...

Comment: Thanks Daniel.do you have any example?

Answer (score 0):

To save the file you can use a package like file-saver:

```
npm install file-saver --save
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver/FileSaver';
```

Your function can be as such:

```
downloadCSV(data: any) {
    const blobData = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
    saveAs(blobData, "file_name.csv");
    return window.open(url);
}
```

To download the file use **arraybuffer**::

```
getFile() {
    this.httpClient.get(url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer',headers:headers})
    .subscribe(
        (data) => this.downloadCSV(data), 
        (error) => // Handle error)
    );
}
```

Comment: It seem to be that the issue is in the service that download the file 

this.http.get...

I have 3 differents files, two of them are downloaded fine, the third aint.

Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error”